# Wildfly 9 - Want to expose 1 app to internet and another to intranet

Tags: wildfly

Im working on Wildfly 9 and want to expose 1 app to intranet 10.x.x.x and another to Internet on 200.x.x.x

The question is how you do this in standalone.xml?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have two different interfaces on the machine that will run the sites?

Comment: Yes I have 2 interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not be the answer you want I've done what you're trying to do by fronting Wildfly with Apache.  If you take a look at the [IP based virtual host docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html), you can have Apache handle the virtual host switch.  Basically your Apache .conf file will have something like:

```
<VirtualHost 10.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName internal.host.name

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/internal-app
    ProxyTimeout 360
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 200.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName external.host.name

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/external-app
    ProxyTimeout 360
</VirtualHost>
```

This is using HTTP proxying - AJP may be a bit faster but I've always found the HTTP version easier to implement and maintain.

Again, the downside is that this requires another package to setup and maintain.  Apache is extreamly well supported in the community but that may not help if you're the one doing the work.

Note that this requires the `proxy` and `proxy_http` Apache modules to be enabled.  If you go this route, let me know you O/S and I can tell you how to enable them.

Answer (score 2):

You will need two standalone instances.

It's not possible separate aplications by IP.

This will bind all your apps for the configured IP:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:10.x.x.x}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

You can add other interface, but you can't apply that for only one app.